# How to get data contain white space using ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, whitespace

I've a problem when i try to get data with white space. When there is white space, it only get the first word.

[Data on database contain white space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJFj7.png)

When selected the dropdown, this alert will appear and it display nothing. If there is no white space, it will display the data.

[Alert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1imni.png)

This is my ajax function

```
function tampiltugas(namatema)
{
    url = urlumum+"Pengetahuan/Tema1/get_daftar_nilai.php?namatema=" + namatema;

    getAjax();
    alert(url + " ");
    ajaxRequest.open("GET",url);
    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
       document.getElementById('tabelTugas').innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
    }
       ajaxRequest.send(namatema);
}
```

This one is dropdown using onchange to call the ajax function

```
<?php 
                echo "<center><div style='display:none;' id='formtugas'>";
                echo "<select id='mapel' name='mapel' class='form-control11' onchange='tampiltugas(this.value);' required>";
                $query1 = mysqli_query($dbh,"SELECT KodeTema, NamaTema FROM tema WHERE KodeKelas='1'");
                echo "<option selected disabled>Pilih Tema</option>";
                while ($ambiltema = mysqli_fetch_array($query1))
                {
                    echo "<option value=".$ambiltema['NamaTema'].">".$ambiltema['NamaTema']."</option>";
                }
                    echo "</select>";
                    echo "</div>";
            ?>
```

Comment: Google "[URL encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)". In it, a literal space is encoded as `+`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need quotes around the values.

```
    echo "<option value='".$ambiltema['NamaTema']."'>".$ambiltema['NamaTema']."</option>";
```

Otherwise the HTML looks like:

```
<option value=info with spaces>info with spaces</option>
```